# Ruby variable scope: access rack.env from inside an existing ruby class?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, scope, rack, env

I have a simple class:

```
class Repository
  class << self
    def find(id)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

It is called like this throughout our app:

```
 thing = Repository.find("abc")
```

We are in a Sinatra/rack environment. During the request phase we do something like this:

```
  env['org'] = 'acme'
```

What I'd like to do is be able to get access to `'acme'` from inside the class `Repository`, without having to explicitly pass it in. There are so many calls to this class all over the place that it would be a pain to pass in the value each time through the find method e.g., `find(id,org = nil)`. I thought maybe there's a way to include the rack gem in Repository, and get at it that way, but so far no luck. Global variables are out - has to be scoped to the request.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I think having a variable that changes like that inside a class method is asking for trouble, it breaks the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter#In_object-oriented_programming) by reaching across boundaries. Instead, I'd wrap it in a Sinatra helper which then passes the second argument by default.

```
helpers do
  def find( s )
    Repository.find( s, env['org'] )
  end
end
```

and modify the `Repository`'s `find` method to take the second argument.

Comment: Yeah I pretty much ended up doing that. It was a lot of refactoring, but I agree that what I was trying to do as a shortcut up there was a total kludge.